# Lex file not reading characters or words in file

Tags: lex

Im working on a Lex problem that displays the number of characters, words, and lines on a text file that the user puts in the terminal. The output displays the correct number of Lines but the incorrect number of characters and 0 for number of words.

Down below is my code

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int charNum = 0, wordNum = 0, lineNum = 0;
%}
%%
.*\n { charNum++; lineNum++; }
 ([a-zA-Z0-9])* { wordNum++; charNum += strlen(yytext); }
. { charNum++; }
%%
int yywrap(void)
{
}
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
   if(argc >2){
      printf("Too many arguments");
   }
   yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   yylex();
   printf("Number of character: %d\n",charNum);
   printf("Number of words: %d\n",wordNum);
   printf("Number of Lines: %d\n",lineNum);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your first pattern ".*\n" matches any line. So only this pattern gets matched and all the other patterns don't.

You can change the first pattern to match just the newline character: "\n". That should fix the problem.